# file decryption, encrypted with vim blowfish

Tags: linux, vim

when i try to decrypt abc.json using command

```
vim abc.json
```

i got the following message

E821: File is encrypted with unknown method

please help.

Comment: How have you encrypted your file?

Comment: actually it is done by one of my friend on their computer.

Comment: Do you have Vim version 7.4.399 or higher?

Comment: Check vim --version for `Included patches`

Comment: Included patches: 1-52

Comment: There you go. You need more recent Vim to use Blowfish2.

Answer (score 5):

To use blowfish2 encryption in Vim, you need Vim version 7.4.399 or higher.